# Android ListView-like scrolling WITHOUT the ListView

Tags: android-listview, android-canvas, android-view, android

I've been Googling like crazy for a while now, and I simply can't find any answers to the question: is it possible to implement the Android List scrolling, without using an actual list UI?

**I'm trying to make a grid of rectangles** *such as the kind you would find in a typical game app* **respond to finger movement in the same way that it does using Android lists** (bounce on the bounds, the 'flick' effect, etc), but all of the approaches I've found involve over-complicated solutions involving extending the list, defining XML layouts, etc.

Would it not be possible to simply give an object variables for `'document' height`, `'viewable' height` and `y-offset`? I'm happy to give the delta (MS since last update) to the object on every update. It would also be good if the actual interactive region was also definable.

*Additionally; are there strong advantages to using the ListView instead that I'm missing? I assume responsiveness comes into play, but I'm quite happily managing that manually at the moment.*

Comment: I would expect game engines to offer their own "grid of rectangles such as the kind you would find in a typical game app", with support for game tiles, tile recycling, etc. "are there strong advantages to using the ListView instead that I'm missing?" -- memory consumption.

Comment: I'm not currently using a game engine... it's all handwritten. I'm also happy to manage the recycling aspect as well (it's a pretty simple formula). Regarding memory consumption, it seems to me that a ListView would use more because it would have integrated UI features that I would not use etc. Cheers for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) directly, assuming you only need vertical scrolling.

Comment: That seems to be what I was looking for! Although it's a shame there's so many requirements involved in implementing it