# ScrollView not capturing movement

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Based on the answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812104/android-listview-like-scrolling-without-the-listview), I'm making a heavily-customized scrolling list, and I wish to capture the child view offset (letting the basic Android functionality handle flicking and bouncing on overscroll etc).

The offset however is always returning 0. Ideas greatly appriciated

```
package com.example.svexample
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
public class ScrollViewTest {
    private static final String TAG = ScrollViewTest.class.getSimpleName();
    private ScrollView sv;
    private View v;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public ScrollViewTest(Context context) {
        v = new View(context);
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        v.setBottom(800); v.setRight(400);
        sv = new ScrollView(context);
        sv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        sv.setBottom(400); sv.setRight(400);
        //The next two lines don't seem to help...
        //LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(400, 600);
        //sv.setLayoutParams(lp);
        sv.addView(v);
    }
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        sv.draw(canvas);
        v.draw(canvas);
        Log.d(TAG, "Scroll is: " + sv.getScrollY());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to feed my app `onTouchEvent` to the `ScrollView` in order for it to be interactive (since it was created programatically). I would have assumed the Android UI elements do this automatically but in this case apparently not.